# Array inside assosiative array

Tags: php, arrays

I want to create an assosiative array which it will have as one of its elements an other array (not assosiative)

```
$temp= array(
    'elem1' => $data1,
    'elem2' => $data2,
    'elem3' => $data5,
  );
```

$data2 is a simple array already constructed. However, I cannot find the right syntax for doing that. By applying the classic following I cannot get the values of elem2.

```
while ($element=each($temp))
  {
    echo $element['key'];
    echo " - ";
    echo $element['value'];
    echo "<br/>";
  }
```

Comment: do a print_r of your $temp array and post it so we can see the full structure. Also, does `$data1/$data2/$data5` have a key named `key` and `value`?

Comment: So, what exactly do you want to do with the non-associative array? You can only access keys that exist.

Comment: Based on what you wrote: $data2 is an array. In the second pass of the while loop, $element['value'] will be $data2. You are trying to use echo to print the array $data2. You need to use something else, such as print_r.

Comment: inside your while loop like that, `$element` will have the same value and structure of the `$dataN` arrays. So if those are non-associative arrays, you need to access the values just like you would with `$data1/$data2/$data5`

Comment: @JonathanKuhn $element will be the return value of the each function. It is a four-element array with indexes 0, 1, key, and value. Therefore, $element['value'] will have the same structure as $dataN.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn What I wrote is NOT what you wrote. I stated very clearly that $element is a 4-element array that in no way has the structure or value of the $dataN arrays. $element['value'] - one element of $element - will have the same value and structure as $dataN.

Comment: @kainaw my fault. I was assuming `each` just returned the current value and incremented the internal pointer. Can't say I've ever used each in favor of a simple foreach loop. So then the question would be: how do I access the second level of a 2d array.

Answer (score 0):

It's not quite clear from your question, but depending on the structure of `$data2`, printing its values separated by commas may suffice:

```
foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
    echo $key, ' - ';
    if (is_array($value)) {
        echo implode(',', $value);
    }
    else {
        echo $value;
    }
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Comment: I want to create $temp including $data2 as to send it with json_encode back to client

Comment: @ILIAS The question says that you're trying to read the array. If you already created it, just use `json_encode($temp)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can echo the values in this way:

```
foreach($temp as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo " - ";
    if(is_array($value)) {
        echo "Array: # ";
        foreach($value as $value_key => $value_value) {
            echo $value_key." - ".$value_value." # ";
        }
    } else {
        echo $value;
    }
    echo "<br/>";
  }
```

Comment: Ok, but how to send $temp to client?

Comment: @ILIAS: don't know what you mean. Can't see anything in your question. I think you should make a new question of it.

Comment: echo json_encode($temp); sends to client (ajax call) the content of $temp. However $temp does not include $data2 content. This is my problem

Comment: What is not working with json_encode? Do a var_dump($temp) and show it to us.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$data = ['elem1' => '1', 'elem2' => ['red','blue','orange' ],'elem3' => '3'];
$tmp ='';
foreach ($data as  $key => $value ) {
  $tmp .= $key.' - ' ;
  if (is_array($value)) {
      $tmp.= implode(',', $value).' ';
  }else {
      $tmp .= $value. ' ';
  }
}
echo json_encode($tmp);
```